# Increase Map Availability in Geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, tomcat

I have an application which access same map from two geoserver using loadbalancing concept
the map is accessed using WMS service.
where the two geoserver connected to a single same POSTGIS database.
even the both tomcat is alloted with 3GB of RAM but the map rendering is still too slow

Is this have anything to do with the performance of POSTGreSQL??

is there any way to increase map availability ?

Please help me

Comment: What efforts have you made to *measure it* and see? Do you log query durations on your PostgreSQL server? Check out PgBadger, pg_stat_statements, `log_query_min_duration`, etc. There are also request performance tools for appservers like Tomcat that can tell you what parts of your code spent the longest time waiting. You can also use system level metrics (load, cpu, memory utilization, I/O load, etc) to reason about bottlenecks in performance. Don't guess, *measure*!

Comment: thanku  Craig for your response will u please give me some tutorial to measure the performance really am new to all these

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization and the numerous links from there. Time to start studying, there's lots to learn. Or, if you don't have the time to study, http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/

Comment: Is GeoWebCache enabled for your GeoServers? Have you installed the native JAI and JAI Image I/O extensions? A lot of factors can affect the GeoServer rendering performance, as stated here: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/index.html

Comment: did you follow the suggestions here http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/index.html

Comment: @iant i do followed the procedure but still facing slow rendering of map after a particular zoom level the map work fine but its only last for some time

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that load balancing works for high-traffic sites. Your problem seems to be related with the fact that tiles are created on the fly from the DB, instead of created on the DB once and then being cached in your server.

Perhaps adding a caching solution for tiles might help: Check http://giscollective.org/tutorials/web-mapping/wmsseven/ for possible solutions.

Such a solution for GeoServer would probably be [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/) as already others have suggested.